# ANGULARJS how to add fields to a collection?

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I've a very simple app in AngularJS that use a full REST (sails) backend.

In my services.js I've declared a resource like

```
MyServices.factory('Post', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
      return $resource('/post/:PostId', {}, {
      //query: { isArray:true }
      });
}]);
```

then in my controller view I've got

```
MyControllers.controller('PostEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Post', '$location', 'flash', '$http', '$rootScope', function($scope, $routeParams, Post, $location, flash, $http, $rootScope ) {
    $scope.post = Post.get({PostId: $routeParams.PostId});
```

When I save the post, If not present, I want to add a field ($scope.post.owner) to add a relationship in my model, so I use this function:

```
   $scope.savePost = function () {
        if ($rootScope.currentUser) {
           $scope.post.owner = $rootScope.currentUser;
           }
        $scope.post.$save({ PostId: $scope.post.id });
        $location.path("/post/"+$routeParams.PostId);
    };
```

I've got no errors but, I don't see the new field in the post requests. 
So far I try also to use $scope.post.push() but without luck.

Comment: push is for array, post is an object. Your cde seems fine to me, are you sure your $rootScope.currentUser is defined ?

Comment: Yes, verified with console.log. I think that Angular won't add post.owner because is not in the initial response.

Comment: No, when using angular-resource, you can create a new epty object, and add fields too it and then perform a $save. This is typically what i do when i'm in my creation forms. So thos definitively should works, did you console $rootScope.currentUser in the $scope.savePost ? I prefer to be sure. And use the debogguer to see the value of $scope.post on the line `$scope.post.$save`

Comment: Modified the savePost function for debug purpose ... inside "if" the currentUser is defined. after the $scope.post.owner = $rootScope.currentUser; the post object has no owner value as before the post.$save

Comment: I have no idea  of what is going on. Can you set a plnkr / js fiddle of you edit page ? We're definitively missing something, but i think we're lacking some piece of code to be able to answer. Can you try to log a your $scope.post object just below $scope.post.owner in the 'if' statement ? This has to be fine, if not, you may have a typo in your code you didn't reproduced here.

Comment: I've also try this '$scope.post.owner ="test"' and still got no value on that field. Should I have to modify the HTML template in order to have some hidden field to bind the '$scope.post.owner' ?

Comment: That a totally stupid test but i want to be sure, can you remove the `$location.path` line or put it in the .then function of the promise returned by `$save` ? There has to be something wrong here, but i definitively can't say what.

Comment: Solved! seems that '$scope.post.owner' is a kind of a reserved name. If i try to add different field '$scope.post.owner_test' my code works ... F****K I've to change all my models relationship :)

Comment: I just searched in all angular.js/angular-resource.js code, There is nothing about a `owner` field that would make it reserved. Are you sure you didn't had any typo somewhere ? That's just doesn't make any sense^^

Comment: You are right, is not angular issue.  As soon as I change my data model in order to use owner_test as name for the relationship in my data model, I got the same behavior and "owner_test" is not added anymore to the scope ... I give up :)